# Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my actual error:

> Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UIApplication.m:3315.

Previously the code was working fine even in IOS 8.4.

With IOS 9 plus this error is showing when executing the Below piece of Code :

```
TabBarVC *newview =[[TabBarVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabBarVC" bundle:Nil];                            
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[TabBarVC alloc] init] ];
[self.navController pushViewController:newview animated:YES];
```

To be exact I am trying to Re-enter my app using previously stored user - session.

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Authenticate..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];
NSString *success=[WEbServiceManager loginWithEmail2:val Type:@"Normal" SocialId:@"0" Devicetoken:returnAValue];

if ([success intValue]==1) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[val stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] forKey:@"username"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Normal" forKey:@"type"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    isGeneralLogin=@"Normal";
    [store setObject:@"TRUE" forKey:@"IsFirstTime"];

    strGlobalUserId=userInfo.userId;

    NSString *strSpecialChannel= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ce_%@",userInfo.userId];

    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:strSpecialChannel block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel n.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to subscribe to the broadcast channel .");
        }
    }];


TabBarVC *newview =[[TabBarVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabBarVC" bundle:Nil];                            
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[TabBarVC alloc] init] ];
[self.navController pushViewController:newview animated:YES];
```

Below is the code which I am using to Login first time and it is perfect.

Comment: format the error and code. Add more information.

Answer (score 3):

@Santanu Das .
A few things have changed and you need to be sure that your UIWindow has "rooted" a valid controller before doing anything, so it would be something like this:

```
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window setRootViewController:nav];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Got it?

Comment: So helpful on my problem which had nothing to do with this but actually was... the same problem. Thanks!